# Python: Search .xlsx file for certain XML tags

Tags: python, xml, xlsx

I want to search a .xlsx file for a certain XML tag - for example, to check if there exists an  tag anywhere in the .xlsx file.

My current plan is to un-zip the .xlsx file and then search all .xml files for the tag in question. Is there a standard library for this, or an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def xlsxHasEntity(filename):                                                                                            
   input_zip = ZipFile(filename)                                                   
   xml_files = [name for name in input_zip.namelist() if name.endswith("xml")]  
   raw_files = {name: input_zip.read(name) for name in xml_files}                                                      
   for raw_filename in raw_files:                                                  
      if "<!ENTITY" in raw_files[raw_filename]:                                    
         return True                                                               
   return False
```

The above is my current solution which seems to be working. Thought I'd share it in case anyone comes to this question in the future.